# How to put an image element Dynamically by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Form_Valid_JS</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form" id="form">
<label style="font-size:18px"><strong> Name</strong> </label><br><br><div id="error"> </div>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]{0,10}" onBlur="fvalidity()" onFocus="Focus()">; 
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" pattern="[a-zA-Z\s]{0,10}" onBlur="lvalidity()">
<input type="submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
<script>
function fvalidity()
{
    var txt="";
    if( document.getElementById("fname").validity.patternMismatch)
    {
        txt="*Only Alphabet max 10 Characters.";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("fname").value=="")
    {
        txt="Field is Empty!!";
    }
    if(txt!="")
    {
        img();
        var s=document.getElementById("error");
        s.innerHTML=txt;
        s.style.visibility="visible";
    }
}
function img()
{
    var sample=document.createElement("img");
    var t= document.createAttribute("src");
    t.value="../cross_script.png";
    sample.setAttributeNode(t);
    var id=document.createAttribute("id");
    id.value="img";
    sample.setAttributeNode(id);
    document.getElementById("form").appendChild(sample);

}
</script>
```

I want to put an image dynamically after the each input field to show the Tick or Cross sign. But when i do that it put the image in the last  after the submit button what is the correct procedure to put a image after each input field dynamically. I mean i make a function and later i call it when doing validation. not. dynamically i make the Elements and tags and apply Cs on it and show on the page after each input field.

Answer (score 2):

In that case you need to pass the reference to the input field after which the image to be inserted like

```
function img(target) {
    var sample = document.createElement("img");
    sample.src = "../cross_script.png";
    document.getElementById("form").appendChild(sample);
    if (target.nextSibling) {
        target.parentNode.insertBefore(sample, target.nextSibling)
    } else {
        target.parentNode.appendChild(sample)
    }
}
```

then

```
img(document.getElementById("fname"));
```

Comment: There is a problem we can create dynamically... i assign the id to <img> of input tag that later i can remove on Focus event.  But it delete all the <img> beacuse it assign the same id to all <img>.. i want to remove focus input image.

Comment: i make a id to apply css that it will appear a message by z index on the the input field after validation.. but i don't know whats going on. my both message are not shown properly .1st one is perfect but the 2nd is not on the position it will automatically goes under the 1st message div.. please check it .... http://jsfiddle.net/p9dhsz80/